# toLocaleDateString returning String without caring of locale

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, discord.js

I'm developping a Discord bot in NodeJS with Discord.js, and I wanted to parse a date in format "YYYY-MM-DD" and display in long fr-FR format.

I tried :

```js
var dateSortie = new Date("2018-06-03");
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
console.log(dateSortie.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options));
```

And no matters the locale (fr-Fr, de-De, ...), it's always returning `"2018 M06 3, Sun"`.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sourcing from [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500) GitHub issue:

> By default `--with-intl=small-icu` is used to build node, which
>   contains just the en-US locale *[...]*. You will need to either build
>   node with `--with-intl=full-icu` or `--with-intl=system-icu` if you
>   want to be able to use more locales. The reason node is built with a
>   smaller ICU by default is file size.

Besides building your own version of node, an alternative seems to be to install the [`full-icu`](https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm) module.

Comment: I'm not a good developper yet, didn't know how to do what you said. I installed the full-icu module and tried to do `npm build --with-intl=full-icu` or `node index.js --with-intl=full-icu` but the problem is still there ...

Comment: The build flags are for building node itself, not for building your application. If you don't want to build node yourself, install the `full-icu` package. When you install the package, it prints out full instructions on how to use it.

Comment: Didn't saw it, it's working on Heroku without global install and `worker: node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu index.js` procfile